# Edit Group Label's Text In Crystal Reports?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Is there any way to set programatically the group label's text in CR for VS 2010?

For example, in a bar chart change the name of the bars?

Thank you in advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be what you meant by "programmatically", but here is how you would do it in CR without the VS aspect.

Go to the 'Group Expert' -> Select the group you want to rename and hit 'Options' -> Go to the 'Options' tab -> Select the 'Customize Group Name Field' checkbox -> Select 'Use a Formula as a Group Name' -> Enter a formula for naming your groups.

[image: Group options dialog]

Comment: Thank you for answering, but maybe I expressed it incorrectly, what I need to know It's if I can change specifically the bar's names in a bar chart

Thank you in advice!

Comment: @user1089799 That will change the way the groups are displayed in the bar chart.

Answer (score 0):

You could base your group on a formula field, then change the formula field programmatically.